# Assign parameter type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this code in JavaScript ES6:

```
data = [{name:'Peter'}];
const first_name = data.find(o => o.Name === 'name').Value;
```

I want to migrating to TS, in my tsconfig.json file I set:

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```

and now I'm getting:

```
 Parameter 'o' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

I tried:

```
const first_name = data.find(o:object => o.Name === 'name').Value;
```

but then I got:

```
Error:  ',' expected.
```

It's my first day with TS, so, how can I use "Array.find" with TypeScript? Do I need to add a @type library?

Comment: @type will not be needed. i paste your code to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ , turn on noImplicitAny. And i had no error. Pls check it again

Comment: `const first_name = data.find(o:object => o.Name === 'name').Value;` is wrong syntax, try `const first_name = data.find((o:object) => o.Name === 'name').Value;` with braces

Answer (score 2):

Your typing is just wrong

```
data = [{name:'Peter'}];
const first_name = data.find(o => o.Name === 'name').Value;
```

assuming you have the interface people such as

```
interface People {
name: string;
}
```

The type for data will be Array (or People[]). Here you are finding on the `Name` property (camelcase) instead of `name` all lowercase

Moreover, you want to get the `Value` property but this property does not exists in your `People` interface which is an error…

[This will work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20People%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20data%3A%20People%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7Bname%3A%20'Peter'%2C%20firstName%3A'Pan'%7D%5D%3B%0Aconst%20firstName%20%3D%20data.find(o%20%3D%3E%20o.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20'name').firstName%3B%0A):

```
interface People { 
    name: string;
    firstName: string;
}

const data: People[] = [{name: 'Peter', firstName:'Pan'}];
const firstName = data.find(o => o.name === 'name').firstName;
```

Note that the good naming practice in TS is to use camelCase, therefore you should use "name" and "value" for the properties name (and not PascalCase), same story for the snake_case of first_name which should be `firstName`